# Rails eager loading detected when saving with has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Bullet** gem detected an eager loading on create. Consider the following models:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_banks
  has_many :banks, through: :user_banks
end

class Bank < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :currency

  has_many :user_posts
  has_many :users, through: :user_banks
end

class UserBank < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :bank
end
```

In my controller, when creating user:

```rb
  # GET /user/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # POST /users
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      redirect_to user_path(@user), notice: I18n.t('views.action.created')
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.fetch(:user, {}).permit(:name, :email, bank_ids: [])
  end
```

I've got an error;

```js
Bullet::Notification::UnoptimizedQueryError:
  user: ruby
  POST /admin/users
  USE eager loading detected
    Bank => [:country]
    Add to your query: .includes([:country])
  Call stack
    /src/app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb:36:in `create'
```

The Rails code that eager loads has_many through associations is unfortunately a bit buggy.
How do I solve this? to eager load the `country` and `currency` of the `Bank`.

If you will try in Rails console something like this;

```rb
[1] pry(main)> User.new(name: 'test', email: 'test@test.com', bank_ids: [1, 2]).save!

  Country Load (1.3ms)  SELECT `countries`.`id`, `countries`.`created_at`, `countries`.`updated_at`, `countries`.`code` FROM `countries` WHERE `countries`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Currency Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `currencies`.* FROM `currencies` WHERE `currencies`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Country Load (1.3ms)  SELECT `countries`.`id`, `countries`.`created_at`, `countries`.`updated_at`, `countries`.`code` FROM `countries` WHERE `countries`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Currency Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `currencies`.* FROM `currencies` WHERE `currencies`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  User Create (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `email`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('test', 'test@test.com', '2020-06-25 06:18:50', '2020-06-25 06:18:50')
  UserBank Create (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO `user_banks` (`user_id`, `bank_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1, 1, '2020-06-25 06:18:50', '2020-06-25 06:18:50')
  UserBank Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `user_banks` (`user_id`, `bank_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1, 2, '2020-06-25 06:18:50', '2020-06-25 06:18:50')
```

Comment: Please include the call stack from bullet as well, the create action does not fetch anything from the database so we need some more context please. Also maybe include the show action and views as this is where you redirect after successfully saving the user.

Comment: `Call stack` is from the line of `if @user.save` inside the create method. I think it is too much to add views to this question.

Comment: With the code you show here it's unfortunately not possible to answer your question then.

Comment: I updated my question. My problem here is `N+1` How do I solve when creating

Comment: Are you sure that the bullet warning is not generated after the redirect when you are rendering the show view?

Comment: Yes, I also tried it in rails console, and you can see N+1 error.

Comment: Does `User.new(name: 'test', email: 'test@test.com', Bank.eager_load(:country, :currency).find([1, 2])).save!` solve your problem?

Comment: @FabianWinkler Yes, this will solve the problem, any other alternative? I tried this `User.new(name: 'test', email: 'test@test.com', banks: Bank.includes(:country, :currency).find([1, 2])).save!`

Comment: @do_Ob In theory your approach should work as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```rb
User.new(name: 'test',
         email: 'test@test.com',
         banks: Bank.eager_load(:country, :currency).find([1, 2])
        ).save!
```